# Qt: setting an override cursor from a non-GUI thread

Tags: qt, mouse-cursor

A while ago I wrote a little RAII class to wrap the `setOverrideCursor()` and `restoreOverrideCursor()` methods on `QApplication`.  Constructing this class would set the cursor and the destructor would restore it.  Since the override cursor is a stack, this worked quite well, as in:

```
{
   CursorSentry sentry;
   // code that takes some time to process
}
```

Later on, I found that in some cases, the processing code would sometimes take a perceptible time to process (say more than half a second) and other times it would be near instantaneous (because of caching).  It is difficult to determine before hand which case will happen, so it still always sets the wait cursor by making a `CursorSentry` object.  But this could cause an unpleasant "flicker" where the cursor would quickly turn from the wait cursor to the normal cursor.

So I thought I'd be smart and I added a separate thread to manage the cursor override.  Now, when a `CursorSentry` is made, it puts in a request to the cursor thread to go to the wait state.  When it is destroyed it tells the thread to return to the normal state.  If the `CursorSentry` lives longer than some amount of time (50 milliseconds), then the cursor change is processed and the override cursor is set.  Otherwise, the change request is discarded.

The problem is, the cursor thread can't technically change the cursor because it's not the GUI thread.  In most cases, it does happen to work, but sometimes, if I'm really unlucky, the call to change the cursor happens when the GUI thread gets mixed in with some other X11 calls, and the whole application gets deadlocked.  This usually only happens if the GUI thread finishes processing at nearly the exact moment the cursor thread decides to set the override cursor.

So, does anyone know of a safe way to set the override cursor from a non-GUI thread.  Keep in mind that most of the time, the GUI thread is going to be busy processing stuff (that's why the wait cursor is needed after all), so I can't just put an event into the GUI thread queue, because it won't be processed until its too late.  Also, it is impractical to move the processing I'm talking about to a separate thread, because this is happening during a paint event and it needs to do GUI work when its done (figuring out what to draw).

Any other ideas for adding a delay to setting the override cursor would be good, too.

Comment: did you ever find a good solution for this? I want to do almost exactly the same thing / same problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other way besides a Signal-Slot connection going to the GUI thread followed by a `qApp->processEvents()` call, but like you said, this would probably not work well when the GUI thread is tied up.

The documentation for [QCoreApplication::processEvents](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents-2) also has some recommended usages with long event processing:

> This function overloads processEvents(). Processes pending events for
>   the calling thread for maxtime milliseconds or until there are no more
>   events to process, whichever is shorter.
>
> You can call this function
>   occasionally when you program is busy doing a long operation (e.g.
>   copying a file).
>
> Calling this function processes events only for the
>   calling thread.

If possible break up the long calls in the paint event and have it periodically check to see how long it has been taking.  And in any of those checks, have it set the override cursor then from in the GUI Thread.

Often a [`QProgressBar`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprogressbar.html) can go a long way to convey the same information to the user.

Another option that could help quite a bit would be to render outside of the GUI thread onto a QImage buffer and then post it to the GUI when it is done.